# 500 error Django Rest Frameworks Serializer

Tags: django, django-serializer

newbie here. I am following a React+Django tutorial (create a store) in which we are using Django RestFrameworks (and this is my first time using it). We are using serializers with JWT tokens for authentication. The problem I'm having is when I try to create a new "order" in the page, I get a 500 error:

Internal Server Error: /api/order/add
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 103, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
raise exc
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/backend/base/views/order_views.py", line 59, in addOrderItems
return Response(serializer.data)
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 555, in data
ret = super().data
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 253, in data
self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 522, in to_representation
ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1886, in to_representation
return method(value)
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/backend/base/serializers.py", line 74, in get_user
return serializer.data
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 555, in data
ret = super().data
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 253, in data
self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 522, in to_representation
ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1886, in to_representation
return method(value)
File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/GitHub/ecommerce/backend/base/serializers.py", line 19, in get_name
name = obj.first_name
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'first_name'
[17/Sep/2022 19:03:07] "POST /api/order/add HTTP/1.1" 500 147510

**My serializers.py file is as follows:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from .models import Product, Order, OrderItem, ShippingAddress



class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True)
    isAdmin = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields= ['id', 'first_name','email', 'name', 'isAdmin']
    
    def get_isAdmin(self, obj):
        return obj.is_staff
    
    def get_name(self, obj):
          name = obj.first_name
          if name == '':
              name = obj.email
          return name 

class UserSerializerWithToken(UserSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True)
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'name', 'isAdmin', 'token']
        
    def get_token(self, obj):
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(obj)
        return str(token.access_token)
        

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields= '__all__'
        
class ShippingAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ShippingAddress
        fields= '__all__'
        
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields= '__all__'

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orderItems = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True) #formerly orders
    shippingAddress = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True)
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields= '__all__'
    
    def get_orderItems(self,obj): #former get_orders
        items = obj.orderitem_set.all()
        serializer = OrderItemSerializer(items, many = True)
        return serializer.data
    
    def get_shippingAddress(self,obj):
        try:
            address = ShippingAddressSerializer(obj.shippingAddress, many=False) #we can do it like this because this is  a 1:1 field
        except:
            address = False
            
        return address
    
    def get_user(self,obj):
        user =User.objects.all() #previously obj.user.all(), but that gave an error
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, many = False)
        return serializer.data
```

**my user_views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework import status

from base.models import User
from base.serializers import  UserSerializer, UserSerializerWithToken


class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(self.user).data
        for key, value in serializer.items():
            data[key]=value
        return data
 
class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
    
    
@api_view(['POST'])    
def registerUser(request):
    data=request.data
    try:
        user=User.objects.create(
            first_name = data['first_name'],
            #last_name= data['last_name'], this was causing error: fields didn't match
            username = data['email'], 
            email = data['email'],
            password = make_password(data['password'])
    )
            
        serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(user, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    except:
        message={'detail':'User with this email already exists'}
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
 

@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def updateUserProfile(request):
    user = request.user 
    serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(user, many=False)
    
    data =request.data 
    user.first_name=data['first_name']
    user.username=data['email']
    user.email=data['email']
    if data['password'] != ' ' :
        user.password =  make_password(data['password']) 
    
    user.save() 
    
    return Response(serializer.data)

    
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def getUserProfile(request):
    user = request.user 
    serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def getUsers(request):
    users = User.objects.all() 
    serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

We are using Django's default User model for the tutorial.

Please, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance

UPDATE: Someone asked to see the models, here they are:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Product (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True) 
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    ingredients = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 2000, null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    numReviews = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default = 0)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    countInStock = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default = 0)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    

class Review(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True) 
    rating = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default = 0)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length = 2000, null=True, blank=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rating)
    
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    paymentMethod = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    taxPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    shippingPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    totalPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    is_Paid = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    paidAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    isDelivered = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    deliveredAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.createdAt)
    
class OrderItem(models.Model):
      product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
      order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
      name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True) 
      qty = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default = 0)
      price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
      image = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True) 
      id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
      
      def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)
        
        
class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    postalCode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    shippingPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.address)
```

Comment: please share the models also

Comment: I added them at the bottom of the original question s an update. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, you are trying to retrieve the `first_name` from a [Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api-reference) rather than from an individual instance/object.

This is because in the `get_user` method, you are passing a `Queryset` to the `UserSerializer`, rather than a `User` object.

I guess what you are trying to do is pass the user associated with the `order` to the `UserSerializer`. If this is the case, you can change the get_user method to the following:

```
def get_user(self,obj):
    serializer = UserSerializer(obj.user)
    return serializer.data
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, this is why I AM able to register a user, create a profile, etc, but I can't place an order (I am using a different serializer to create the user, accessing the User object, but in the second case, I am trying to access the data sent from the front end, right?)?  So, just to make sure I understand: in the OrderSerializer, change the get_user method as you suggested, right?

Comment: In short: yes. 
When instantiating a Serializer, you can do it by providing a single instance, or by providing multiple objects (a `Queryset` of objects). If you do the latter, you will have to user the additional flag `many=True`. However, in the `OrderSerializer`, you are passing a queryset of users **without** providing this flag - hence the error.

Comment: @MarilynMarquez, no problem. If my answer helped you, please do not forget to upvote it or select it as the accepted answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can access user by the order object

```
 def get_user(self,obj):
    serializer = UserSerializer(obj.user)
    return serializer.data
```